# How do I add a folder automatically to the system PATH upon login for CentOS v6.9 with TC shell?

Tags: centos, path, tcsh

I am accessing a remote CentOS v6.9 computer (with UltraVNC, but this detail may not be relevant). With user privileges, I want to add a folder automatically to the system PATH environment variable upon login.

Using `echo $SHELL`, I find that my user profile is using the TC shell, according to [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7612/customize-89075/index.html).

```
[username@computername ~]$ echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/tcsh
```

As much as I search StackExchange, I can't find out how to add to the PATH automatically upon login with the TC shell.

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-set-path-variable-in-c-shell/), the command to append path settings in ~/.login file (where "~" in the C, Korn, TC, and Z shells is a shortcut representing the path name of your home directory) for a path `/usr/local/stuff` is:

```
echo 'set path = ($path /usr/local/stuff .)' >> ~/.login
```

Alternatively, use the command to append path settings in the ~/.cshrc file

```
echo 'setenv PATH $PATH\:/usr/local/stuff\:.'  >> ~/.cshrc
```

These commands will automatically create the .login and .cshrc files in your home directory if they do not exist. Of course, you can also manually add the text between the ' marks to the corresponding file in your home directory.

To make the changed to your user profile effective immediately without having to logoff and login again, use the `source` command to cause the system to read the current user profile file and execute the commands in this file.

```
source ~/.cshrc
```

Comment: That addition to `~/.cshrc` will also add the current working directory at any given point when you're in the shell to the path. If you take out the last `\:.`, it works perfectly.